# Setting minimum and maximum date range to DateTime input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-core

Is there a way to set a range for DateTime in the View Model, in a way that makes the maximum possible date one can input be the *current date and time (UTC)*, and the minimum date possible be *a year ago*?

Something like `[Range(typeof(DateTime), "06/06/2020 23:43", "Utc.Now")]`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to restrict user input, you can set the following settings on your view.

```
<input asp-for="SelectedDate" max="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm")" min="@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm")" />
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Just as a side note, why doesn't the disabling of dates in the datepicker beyond the min/max work if I change the date format in the `ToString` to anything else, like `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"`? (Validation still works fine, but need to show the errors in the validation as perfectly readable to the user, while retaining the disabled dates).

Comment: You can see this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local).

Comment: Is there any way to set a custom error for min and max?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to validate the DateTime range on server-side, you would define a **custom attribute** to validate your property value.

```
    public class ValidateDate: ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid
                         (object date, ValidationContext validationContext)
        { 
             return (date<= DateTime.Now && date >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
                 ? ValidationResult.Success
                 : new ValidationResult("Invalid date range"); 
        }
    }
```

And your property should be decorated with the attribute

```
[ValidateDate]
public DateTime MyDate{get; set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified answer from [Majid Qafouri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5432783/majid-qafouri)

It works good!

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


    public class ValidateDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid
            (object obj, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(obj);

            return (date <= DateTime.UtcNow && date >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-1))
                ? ValidationResult.Success
                : new ValidationResult("Invalid date range");
        }
    }
```

And your property should be decorated with the attribute

```
    [ValidateDate]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).